# Why does the output in verilog task become x (unknown value) on first cycle?

Tags: verilog

I am confused in task statement in verilog.
I prepared following sample code in order to understand the task behavior.
But the simulation result was different as I had expected.Because I thought task_output 
on first cycle should be zero instead of X(unkown value).
Why does such a problem occur? and Does anyone know how to avoid this problem?
Any help would　be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

[sample code]

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module TaskTest_tb;
parameter CK_PERIOD = 10;
reg simCk;
reg [15:0] task_output;
integer j;


initial begin
    simCk = 0;
    task_output = 0;

    for(j=0; j<16; j=j+1) begin
        @(posedge simCk)  sample_task(8'h01, j[7:0], task_output);
    end
end

always #(CK_PERIOD/2) simCk <= ~simCk; 

task sample_task;
    input [7:0] x;
    input [7:0] count;
    output reg [15:0] y;
    reg [15:0] y_int;
    integer i;
    begin
        @(posedge simCk) y_int <= 0;

        for(i=0; i<count; i=i+1) begin
            @(posedge simCk) y_int <= y_int + x; 
        end
        @(posedge simCk) y <= y_int;
    end
endtask
endmodule
```

[The result of waveform viewer]

[image]

Comment: Is this task aimed at RTL (synthesis) or Verification?

Comment: @Morgan This task itself is just a sample code for the question. I want to use such kind of task as test pattern generator in verification phase. It is  not synthesizable RTL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried initialising the output value of the task. I expect that from the point the task is called it might be continuously driving the value, and `y` within the task is not defined until the last step.

```
task sample_task;
    input [7:0] x;
    input [7:0] count;
    output reg [15:0] y;
    reg [15:0] y_int;
    integer i;
    begin
        y<=0; //<--Added line
        @(posedge simCk) y_int <= 0;

        for(i=0; i<count; i=i+1) begin
            @(posedge simCk) y_int <= y_int + x; 
        end
        @(posedge simCk) y <= y_int;
    end
endtask
```